# visual composer extensions and ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

i have a full ajax wordpress template for my website and visual composer plugin in back-end for live build pages.

it work fine but when in template i call a page via ajax the extension not work,
it seems that the extension elements not added to DOM and their js scripts not recognize them,
i use `jQuery.on()` for my widget elements and it work fine with ajax response data.

is there any way to reinitialize VC extensions after ajax?

meanwhile, if i refresh page it works fine. (without ajax response)

any idea please!?